Livewire variable not being shown in the input view in spite it reaches the view
I have a project in Laravel 11 and Livewire 3. I have Purchase (Compras) Component, which renders two views (Purchases and their lines). I can save the model to the database, the connection from the view to the componeont works. But, the input texts don't show back the updated value of the variables. I know the value comes back from the component because when I debug with Xdebug, the variable has a new value, but the input stays blank, or with the value I assigned at mount(). I put here only the inputs in question (for clarity). The view is enclosed in a div, and, I repeat, the connection works, the updatedFoo() method works. Thanks in advance for any clue you can give. I have spent 30 hours in this, to no avail.
Inputs:
<div class="col-lg-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label">Monto:</label>
                            <input type="number" wire:model="monto" class="form-control" readonly>
                            @error('monto')
                                <span class="form-text text-danger">
                                    <i class="icon-cancel-circle2 mr-2"></i>
                                    {{ $message }}
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <td class="celda">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                    wire:model.live="lineas.{{ $index }}.total" readonly>
                                <div>
                                    @error('lineas.{{ $index }}.total')
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
          </td>

The component:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Rubro;
use App\Models\Compra;
use App\Models\Precio;
use App\Models\Potrero;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Producto;
use App\Models\Proveedor;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class CrearCompras extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public Collection $estancias; //las variables de acá son automáticamente pasadas a la vista blade
    public Collection $potreros;
    public Collection $rubros;
    public Collection $proveedors;

    #[Validate('required')]
    public $fecha = '';

    #[Validate('required')]
    public $proveedor = '';

    #[Validate('required')]
    public $vencimiento = '';


    public $estanciaElegida = '';


    public $potreroElegido = '';

    public $factura = '';

    #[Validate('required')]
    public $tipo = '';

    #[Validate('required')]
    public $moneda = '';

    #[Validate('required')]
    public $monto = '';

    public $notas = '';

    /* public $concepto = ''; */

    #[Validate('required')]
    public $division = '';

    #[Validate('required')]
    public $rubro = '';

    public $potreroObjeto = '';
    /*Sección línea compra*/
    public Collection $rubrosLineas;
    public Collection $productos;
    public $lineas = [];
    protected $rules = [
        'lineas' => 'required|array|min:1',
        'lineas.*.producto_id' => 'required|gt:0',
        'lineas.*.cantidad' => 'required|gt:0',
        'lineas.*.unitario' => 'required|gt:0',
        'lineas.*.descuento' => 'required',
        'lineas.*.iva' => 'required|',
        'lineas.*.rubro' => 'required|',
        'lineas.*.division' => 'required',

    ];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->fecha = now('GMT-3')->format('Y-m-d');
        $this->vencimiento = now('GMT-3')->addDays(30)->format('Y-m-d');
        $this->estancias = Auth::user()->empresa->estancias;
        $this->potreros = collect(); //Esto hace que se transforme en una variable de tipo collection
        $this->rubros = Rubro::where('empresa_id', Auth::user()->empresa_id)->get();
        $this->proveedors = Proveedor::where('empresa_id', Auth::user()->empresa_id)->get();

        /*Sección líneas compras*/
        $this->productos = Producto::where('empresa_id', Auth::user()->empresa_id)->get();
        $this->rubrosLineas = Rubro::where('empresa_id', Auth::user()->empresa_id)->get();
        //Hay que hacerlo con arrays porque Livewire no acepta conexiones wire:model a colecciones.
        //Y el número asignado, en caso de combos, no es el valor, sino el índice de los elementos del combo,
        //salvo en el IVA, no sé por qué. Quizás porque no es foreach
        $this->lineas  = [
            [

                'producto_id' => 1,
                'cantidad' => 1,
                'unitario' => 1,
                'iva' => 0,
                'descuento' => 1,
                'total' => 1,
                'rubro' => 2,
                'division' => 2,
            ]
        ];
    }
    /*Sección líneas compras*/
    public function updatedLineas($value, $key)
    {

        $campo = explode(".", $key)[1];
        if (in_array($campo, ['producto_id', 'cantidad', 'unitario', 'iva', 'descuento'])) {
            $this->calcular();
        }
    }
    public function updatedTotal()
    {
        $i = 8;
    }
    private function calcular()
    //$key y $value DEBEN llamarse así, si no, no anda.
    {
        foreach ($this->lineas as $key => $value) {

            $total = $this->lineas[$key]['cantidad'] *
                $this->lineas[$key]['unitario'] *
                (1 - ($this->lineas[$key]['descuento'] / 100)) *
                (1 + ($this->lineas[$key]['iva'] / 100));

            $this->lineas[$key]['total'] = $total;
            $this->monto = $total;
        }
    }
    /*Fin sección líneas*/
    public function save()
    {
        //Esto lo hago porque Livewire no detecta el elemento seleccionado por defecto
        ($this->tipo === "") ?  $this->tipo = "Contado" : '';
        ($this->moneda === "") ?  $this->moneda = "Dólares" : '';

        $this->validate();
        $dolarUltimo = Precio::dolarUltimo($this->fecha);
        if ($dolarUltimo === 0) {
            $dolarUltimo = session('dolar');
        }
        $montoUsd = 0;
        if ($this->moneda === "Pesos") {
            $montoUsd = round($this->monto / $dolarUltimo, 2);
        } else {
            $montoUsd = $this->monto;
        }
        if ($this->estanciaElegida === "") {
            $this->estanciaElegida = 0;
        }
        if ($this->potreroElegido === "") {
            $this->potreroElegido = 0;
        }

        $compra = compra::create([
            'fecha' => $this->fecha,
            'proveedor_id' => $this->proveedor,
            'vencimiento' => $this->vencimiento,
            'estancia_id' => $this->estanciaElegida,
            'potrero_id' => $this->potreroElegido,
            'factura' => $this->factura,
            'tipo' => $this->tipo,
            'moneda' => $this->moneda,
            'cambio' => $dolarUltimo,
            'monto' => $this->monto,
            'monto_usd' => $montoUsd,

            'division' => $this->division,
            'rubro_id' => $this->rubro,
            'creador_id' => auth()->id(),
            'empresa_id' => Auth::user()->empresa->id,
            'notas' => $this->notas,
        ]);
        return to_route('compras.index')->with('MessageOK', 'compra guardado exitosamente');
    }
    public function updatedEstanciaElegida($value) //Cuando elige estancia, se actualiza la variable
    //enlazada, y automáticamente busca los potreros de esa estancia
    {
        $this->potreros = Potrero::where('estancia_id', $value)->get();
        if ($this->potreros->count() > 0) {
            $this->potreroElegido = $this->potreros->first()->id; //Esta línea es para que elija
            //uno por defecto, si no, HTML elige el primer elemento del select,pero Livewire no se da cuenta y da error
            $this->potreroObjeto = $this->potreros->first();
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.crear-compras');
    }
}


I tried everything, optimizing the cache, adding divs, reading half Laracasts... to no avail.
